# regex to remove <meta name="keyword... strings

Tags: regex

I need to process hundreds of html and php files in a folder to remove old meta keyword tags:

`<meta name="keywords" content="all kinds of words here"/>`

I can run a regular expression in BBEdit to process the folder, but I can't figure out a regular expression to delete the strings. Obviously, the start characters are `<meta name="keywords"` and the ending characters are `/>`

I got as far as `^<meta name="keywords" \/> $` at https://regex101.com/r/bW5lD0/1

But how to I add the random lengths of the meta keywords themselves to the expression to delete them?

Comment: You really should be using a html parser for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex. Just add `[^>]+` which matches every character other than `>` until it encounters one. Also remove the `^` and `$` anchors.

```
<meta name="keywords"[^>]+>
```

and replace with empty string.

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/bW5lD0/2)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Thanks! Works fine. I have a lot to learn when it comes to regex.

Comment: @songdogtech you'll learn it soon, I suppose :) Anyway glad to help :)

Comment: I didn't change my question at all, just added "BBEdit" to it; that's the text editor I use. Awarded answer to you as you were first :)

Comment: @songdogtech apart from being first, this regex is more efficient than the other one, so I assume I got +15 for being the better regex and not being the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta\sname="keywords".*?\/>
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.

https://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/16

Comment: Thanks! Works fine. Interesting that it is different from the @AmitJoki's answer.